# Is Python socket.send limited in size?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a `bytearray`.  I checked its size with `len` and it's 15.000 bytes.  However, when sending it through `s.send()`, where `s` is a socket, only 6000 bytes are sent.

Is this normal ? The next call to `send` doesn't even send the rest.

More details : Even with splittig with 3 sendall it does not work :

```
s.sendall(fbytes[:5000])
s.sendall(fbytes[5000:10000])
s.sendall(fbytes[10000:])
```

Comment: "The next call to `send` doesn't even send the rest."  Could we see that code?

Comment: I'll let someone who has experience with this answer, but considering the docs for [socket.send()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) specifically mention that application is responsible for sending all data, it's likely expected behavior. Maybe their included [HOWTO guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto) might help?

Comment: @DanielWalker the code is too long and convoluted, but the next call to send actually sends an array of 10 bytes like s.send(barr) where barr is super small

Comment: This question needs sufficient code to describe the problem. It currently only shows the interpretation by the OP and this interpretation might be not exact enough. It is not even clear if TCP or UDP is used, even though this makes a difference when answering the question. It is also not clear how the receiving end works, i.e. the error might be (also) there.

Comment: @AaaBbb "The code is too long and convoluted".  Then reduce the code to a [mcve] that still has the same issue and post that.  Without seeing *some* code we can only guess.  You comment below that `.sendall()` is "not working", but it should, so show us what you are doing in both the client and the server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal.  The socket buffer kept by the kernel is only so big.  You can either set up a loop:

```py
while data:
    transmitted = s.send(data)
    data = data[transmitted:]
```

or call `s.sendall(data)` which, in essence, does that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately sendall is not working, the other side still only receives 6014 bytes

Comment: Tried the loop too, and still the same issue

Comment: Does the sending code block?

Comment: No it doesn't and "transmitted" value is the full size (14000 bytes).Maybe the problem is on the receiving end which does not use python

Comment: That’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive more bytes than the limit, there should be the following code somewhere in your Python file.

```py
client.recv(1024)
```

In the above example, 1024 is the number of bytes to read from the client.
If you want more bytes, you can do the following.

```py
bytes_to_recv = 2000
client.recv(bytes_to_recv)
```

Comment: @DanielWalker Okay, I will update my answer

Comment: @DanielWalker Yes, it does take an argument that is an instance of the class int. This is just an example, so replace "something" with a custom integer.